# "Name not found in the directory please use catalog to choose names" Lotus notes error

Tags: lotusscript

I'm getting the error when I pick one of the name which is in the domino directory. All of them who pick the particular name get the same error only for that name.

I have checked with the administrator as well, there is no issue with the name of the person and I don't see any issue with lotus script code also. Please help me to know what's wrong with the code.

Please find the below code.

```
    Dim doc As NotesDocument, maildocCC  As NotesDocument, maildoc  As NotesDocument, docPerson  As NotesDocument
    Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim db As NotesDataBase, dbusers As NotesDataBase
    Dim w As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim viewPerson As NotesView
    Dim body As NotesRichtextItem
    Dim solicitante As NotesName, nam As NotesName, nomeAprovador As NotesName, revisor As NotesName
    Dim i As Integer, x As Integer, u As Integer, z As Integer, qtdRevisores As Integer
    Dim aprovadores As Variant, informativo As Variant, listaRevisores As Variant
    Dim nomesInf As String, nome As String, revisores As String, firstName As String, middleName As String, lastName As String
    Dim nomesIncorretos As String, nomePerson As String
    Dim nomeIncorreto As Boolean
    
    Set db=session.CurrentDatabase
    Set uidoc = w.CurrentDocument
    Set doc=uidoc.document
    
    'Validar
    If doc.addReviewer(0)="" Then
        Msgbox "Please indicate to whom you want to send the analysis!",0+16,"Attention!"
        Call uidoc.GotoField("addReviewer")
        Exit Sub
    End If  
    Set solicitante = session.CreateName(doc.solicitante(0))
    aprovadores=doc.addReviewer
    listaRevisores=doc.revisores
    Forall c  In aprovadores
        Set nam = session.CreateName(c)
        If nam.Abbreviated=solicitante.Abbreviated Then
            Msgbox "The requester cannot be part of the reviewers list!",0+16,"Attention!"
            Call uidoc.GotoField("addReviewer")
            Exit Sub        
        End If      
    End Forall  
    Set dbusers = New NotesDatabase( db.Server , "names.nsf" )
    If Not dbusers.IsOpen Then 
        Messagebox "Unable to open the directory of users!",0+16,"Attention!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    nomeIncorreto=False
    nomesIncorretos="[ "
    Forall a In aprovadores
        Set nam = session.CreateName(a)
        nome=nam.Common
        If Instr(nam.Abbreviated)>0 Then
            If Instr(nam.Abbreviated)>0 Then
                nomeIncorreto=True
                If nomesIncorretos="[ " Then
                    nomesIncorretos=nomesIncorretos + a
                Else
                    nomesIncorretos=nomesIncorretos + ", " + a
                End If  
            Else
                Set viewPerson= dbusers.GetView("($Users)")
                Set dc = viewPerson.GetAllDocumentsByKey(Lcase(nome), False)
                Set docPerson = dc.GetFirstDocument
                If docPerson Is Nothing Then 
                    Msgbox "The name '"+nome+"' was not found in the address book! Please use the notes catalog to select the user!",0+16,"Attention!"                  
                    Call uidoc.GotoField("addReviewer")
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    While Not docPerson Is Nothing
                        firstName=docPerson.FirstName(0)
                        middleName=docPerson.MiddleInitial(0)
                        lastName=docPerson.LastName(0)
                        If middleName="" Then
                            nomePerson=firstName+" "+lastName
                        Else
                            nomePerson=firstName+" "+middleName+" "+lastName
                        End If
                        If nome<>nomePerson Then
                            nomeIncorreto=True
                            If nomesIncorretos="[ " Then
                                nomesIncorretos=nomesIncorretos + nome
                            Else
                                nomesIncorretos=nomesIncorretos + ", " + nome
                            End If
                        End If
                        Set docPerson = dc.GetNextDocument(docPerson)
                    Wend
                End If
            End If
        Else
            nomeIncorreto=True
            If nomesIncorretos="[ " Then
                nomesIncorretos=nomesIncorretos + a
            Else
                nomesIncorretos=nomesIncorretos + ", " + a
            End If  
        End If
    End Forall
    
    If nomeIncorreto Then
        Msgbox "The names "+nomesIncorretos+" ] were not found in the address book! Please use the notes catalog to select the users!",0+16,"Attention!"
        Call uidoc.GotoField("addReviewer")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    doc.reviewerList=Arrayunique(Arrayappend(doc.reviewerList,aprovadores))
    doc.revisores=Arrayunique(Arrayappend(doc.revisores,aprovadores))
    Forall e In aprovadores
        i=i+1
        Set nam = session.CreateName(e)
        nome=nam.Abbreviated
        If i>1 Then
            revisores=revisores + ", " + nome
        Else
            revisores=nome
        End If
    End Forall
    Call uidoc.Close
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Your code generates a MsgBox that says {The name '"+nome+"' was not found in the address book!} but the words in your question here are different. If your question is about why that MsgBox is being triggered, then please make that very clear in the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

I see several issues with your code, and I hope one of them is the culprit.

- You have two identical lines testing `Instr()`, so one of the `else` parts is never executed.
- As far as I know, `Instr()` has 2 parameters.
- For every aprovador you reopen the ($Users) view; it can be done only once
- You can test `dc.Count=0` in order to find out if no documents are found.
- I don’t understand why you’re using `CreateName` all the time; aren’t you sure about the formats of the values you have to compare? Aren’t all fields Names fields?
- Why do you use `GetAllDocumentsByKey` with a 2nd parameter False? Don’t you want an exact match?
- Otherwise, why don’t you use `GetDocumentByKey` to find the matching user?
- Guessing: is the person whose name cannot be found the only one with a middle name?

That’s it for now…